# How to have an open graph object have a reference to multiple opbject types

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Take the famous recipe app as an example: A user can `cook` a `recipe` and let's assume the recipes are by famous `chefs`. As recommended in [Best Practices: Working With Multiple Objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/working-with-multiple-objects/) the chefs are split up into multiple object types: `european chef`, `asian chef`, etc.

When creating the `recipe` object, I can create a *custom property* that can be of type `european chef` or of type `asian chef`, but not both.

Shall I create several optional *custom properties* like "european_chef" of type `european chef` and "asian_chef" of type `asian chef` and then use only the appropriate one?